# How to handle dispose when it's in a generated partial class

Tags: c#, windows-services, dispose

I'm creating a windows service in C# and the dispose method for the `Service` class is implemented in the generated partial class.

Like this:

```
partial class Service
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

How do I handle dispose in this situation?

Comment: Only dispose objects when it is useful to release resources early before the garbage collector gets around to it.  It is *never* useful to do so when the service is disposed, the GC runs a microsecond later.  It is so useless that the Dispose() method you found back in the Designer.cs file never actually gets called.

Comment: Good to know, this was an issue flagged by fxcop and my company is overly dogmatic about these things. Will it cause any problems to dispose it anyway? I'm guessing not if the method never gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to modify `Dispose` implementation then copy it over to the code behind class from `designer.cs`. 
It is one of the few places in `designer.cs`  that should be modified.

The same is true for Windows Form class as well.